# Fatal error: Call to undefined method RW_Meta_Box_User::get_fields()

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes

When I update version of meta boxes in wordpress. I got this error.

Please solve this.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method RW_Meta_Box_User::get_fields()
>   in
>   /home/content/a2pnexwpnas03_data01/86/3452586/html/wp-content/plugins/roker-loader/meta-box/extensions/user_meta/meta_box_user.php
>   on line 40

meta_box_user.php line 40:

```
// Add additional actions for fields
     $fields = self::get_fields( $this->fields );
     foreach ( $fields as $field )
     {
         call_user_func( array( self::get_class_name( $field ), 'add_actions' ) );
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have defined `get_fields()` in `RW_Meta_Box_User`, you may be looking for [`get_fields()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_fields/) without `self::`.

Methods or members marked `self` must be defined inside the class you're using.